# How to get the active selected Outlook Mail Object in pywin32?

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, pywin

I want a script which takes the active selected Mail in Outlook and make an new response mail on this. But I can't find a function to get an active or selected object in pywin32.
I just found these:

```
message.GetLast()
```

and some similar functions. it works but I need a reference to an active chosen mail.

I would choose a filter like "restrict" to find the Mail automatically but I don't know where to get the information for the filters automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection` collection. Note that it can have zero items or more than one item:

```py
import win32com.client # Make sure you have installed the pywin32 package

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
selection = outlook.ActiveExplorer().Selection

if selection.Count > 0:
    message = selection.Item(1)
else:
    message = None
```

Answer (score 0):

The `message.GetLast()` method gets the last item from a collection (`Folder.Items`). Instead, you need to get an Explorer instance by calling the [ActiveExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.activeexplorer) method of the Outlook `Application` class which returns the topmost `Explorer` object on the desktop. Use this method to return the `Explorer` object that the user is most likely viewing. Then you may get the selected items in the Explorer window by getting the `Selection` object (see the corresponding property of the `Explorer` class), for example, the following VBA sample shows how to get selected items:

```
Sub GetSelectedItems() 
 Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer 
 Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection 
 Dim MsgTxt As String 
 Dim x As Integer 
 MsgTxt = "You have selected items from: " 
 
 Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer 
 Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection 
 
 For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count 
   MsgTxt = MsgTxt & myOlSel.Item(x).SenderName & ";" 
 Next x 
 
 MsgBox MsgTxt 
 
End Sub
```

The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages, so you could easily find the required properties and methods that should be used.

Also you may find the [Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activeinlineresponse) property which returns an item object representing the active inline response item in the explorer reading pane. This property returns `null` if no inline response is visible in the Reading Pane.